# What are three refinings or three types of cleansing mentioned in Rigveda 3.26.8?

Tags: rig-veda, translation

I am talking about following [verse of Rigveda](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/sanskrit03/RV0303noaccent.html):

> > **त्रिभिः पवित्रै**रपुपोद्ध्यर्कं हृदा मतिं ज्योतिरनु प्रजानन्।
> > वर्षिष्ठं रत्नमकृत स्वधाभिरादिद्द्यावापृथिवी पर्यपश्यत्॥ ३.०२६.०८
>
> Transliteration:
>
> **tri̱bhiḥ** pa̱vitrai̱rapu̍po̱ddhya1̱̍rkaṃ hṛ̱dā ma̱tiṃ jyoti̱ranu̍ prajā̱nan .
> varṣi̍ṣṭha̱ṃ ratna̍makṛta sva̱dhābhi̱rādiddyāvā̍pṛthi̱vī parya̍paśyat .. 3.026.08
>
> [English translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03026.htm):
>
> 8 Bearing in mind a thought with light accordant, he purified the Sun with **three refinings**;
> By his own nature gained the highest treasure, and looked abroad over the earth and heaven.

What are three refining things or three kind of purification mentioned by "tri̱bhiḥ pa̱vitra..." in this verse of Rigveda?

Comment: This is a translation by Ralph Griffiths, an early orientalist with bad translations.

Comment: @Swami can you suggest another English Translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are **Agni, Surya and Vayu**

- Here is the Hindi translation to the mentioned verse by [Gayatri Pariwar](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v4.37):

  > [image]

  English translation of it would be as follows:

  Sadhakas refine their Atman which is Venerable like **fire, water and sun**, by knowing the supreme light in their antahkarana (inner cause). They excel their Atman with the help of these three forms of Agni. And then after they look earth from everywhere.
- This translation matches with *Sanskrit* commentary by Sayanacharya with a minor change (click on image to magnify):

  > [image]

  Here **Agni (fire), Vayu (air) and Surya (sun) are** considered as three refining.

---

The interpretation mentioned above can be considered as [Yājñikā interpretations](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35312/277). There exists other interpretations also which can be considered Adhyatmika interpretations. For example,

- The [interpretation by Swami Dayananda Saraswati](https://archive.org/stream/RigvedaWww.aryamantavya.in/Rigveda-3-of-5#page/n746/mode/1up) is as follows:

  > PURPOT: A person who is pure in body, speech and mind, and takes pure food, he acquires and learns about real heaven after death.
- This interpretation matches with that of [Damodar Saatvalekar who wrote Subodha Bhashya](https://archive.org/details/RigvedKaSubodhaBhashyaPart2SDSatwalekar1985) on Rigveda.
- Another interpretation by [scholar Tulsi Ram](https://www.elibrary.thearyasamaj.org/book/rig-veda--volume-i#book_reader/1198) is :

  > With **threefold cleansing of body, mind and soul,
  > through  the  purity  of  thought,  word  and  deed,  by
  > inculcation of right knowledge (jnana), right conduct
  > (karma) and right prayer and meditation (upasana),** I
  > purify  the  holy  light  of  the  self,  thereby  lighting  the
  > flame of the spirit in the intelligence with honesty and
  > sincerity  of  the  heart,  and  with  these  foods  and
  > fortifications of the spirit, I redeem the diamond purity
  > and generosity of the soul, and then watch the immensity
  > of heaven and earth participating in the Infinity of the
  > Supreme Self.
- [Vedic Sukta Sanmgraha](https://archive.org/details/VedicSuktaSangrahaGitaPressGorakhpur/page/n237/mode/1up), book from Gitapress translated this verse as follows:

  > [image]

  Here three measures are Yajna (sacrifice), Dana (donation) and Tapa (perseverance) or Shravana, Manana and Nididhyasana.

---

Hence, considering reliable interpretation by Sayanacharya and Dayananad Saraswati whose commentary are most followed and widely accepted, the answer to the question is:

- **Agni (fire), Vayu (air) and Surya (sun)** according to Yajnika interpretation.
- **Mind/thought, speech/word and Karma (deeds)** according to Adhyatmika interpretation.